# Getting multiple counts from two joined tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

So I have two tables, categories and designs. I want to construct a query that will fetch all categories, along with the count of any sub categories (categories.parent_id equal to the categories.id) AND the count of any designs (design.category_id equal to categories.id)

If I try to just get one of these counts, everything works fine, but when I try for both with the following code, the count for both is the same number (and not the correct number) for either.

```
        $this->db->select('categories.id AS id, categories.parent_id AS parent_id, categories.title AS title, 
        categories.description AS description, categories.img_path AS img_path, COUNT(designs.id) AS design_count, 
        COUNT(sub_categories.id) as sub_category_count');
        $this->db->from('categories');
        $this->db->join('designs',                          'categories.id = designs.category_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('categories as sub_categories',     'categories.id = sub_categories.parent_id', 'left');
        $this->db->group_by('categories.id');
```

Any help will be much appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Start by creating the SQL query and executing it with a tool like PHPMyadmin. As long as it doesn't work there, it can't work with any database abstraction (and you have not told which one you're using, it might be limited and you would need to execute a raw SQL query anyway).

Comment: categories is:
id, parent_id, title.    

designs is:
id, category_id, title.      

cheers!

Comment: Is the depth of categories restricted to two levels or unlimited (you should know what I am talking about)?

Comment: @SalmanA just two levels yep, didn't want to over complicate things! cheers

Comment: Can root level categories contain designs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the root categories do not contain designs, here is the query that returns the necessary information:

```sql
SELECT category.id, category.title, subcategory.id, designs.id
FROM categories category
LEFT JOIN categories subcategory ON category.id = subcategory.parent_id
LEFT JOIN designs ON subcategory.id = designs.category_id
WHERE category.parent_id IS NULL
```

Now all you need to do is to apply grouping:

```sql
SELECT category.id, category.title, COUNT(DISTINCT subcategory.id), COUNT(designs.id)
FROM categories category
LEFT JOIN categories subcategory ON category.id = subcategory.parent_id
LEFT JOIN designs ON subcategory.id = designs.category_id
WHERE category.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY category.id, category.title
```

The key here is the use of [`COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id,c.title,
       IFNULL(sc.counted,0) AS subcategories,
       IFNULL(d.counted,0) AS designs
FROM categories c 
     LEFT JOIN 
     ( SELECT parent_id,COUNT(*) AS counted 
         FROM categories GROUP BY parent_id ) sc
       ON c.id=sc.parent_id
     LEFT JOIN
     ( SELECT category_id,COUNT(*) AS counted 
         FROM designs GROUP BY category_id ) d
       ON c.id=d.category_id
WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL ;
```

should get you the desired numbers as raw SQL.